# Unknown Grey Area in Blender

Tags: mesh, error

I have a question about the grey area that I'm facing in blender right now, whenever I try to pan and zoom in & out, this grey area is still in sight and its making my work harder and time consuming.

Even worse, there is one time I accidentally zoom out and I can't find my work anywhere and I have to save another copy for backup. May I know what is the reason of this or is it has anything to do with laptop specifications? because a while back, I never encounter with this kind of experience. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLCTY.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hello, I think you have a units problem, your house is several kilometers long. Anyways most likely you'eh itting the camera view limits, Go to the n panel then View tab and increase the Clip End value

Answer (score 5):

Souds like a clipping problem. You have to manually set the distance that is drawn before and after your position. You can do that in view tab.

[image]

Comment: dont forget that the same goes for each camera in your scene (you can set it in camera options)

Comment: And additionally, even the grid is affected by this in perspective view, that's why everything turns grey.